# How do I proxy _some_ requests to '/' using http-proxy-middleware for Webpack?

Tags: webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server, http-proxy-middleware

I'm trying to solve a unique problem w/ an app where I need to use webpack dev-server's `proxy` functionality to proxy specific requests through to a backend service.

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to handle an odd use case.

I have Webpack DevServer (WDS) serving up my `index.html` for a Single Page App w/ multiple client-side routes.  The SPA makes clientside AJAX/fetch requests to different endpoints that need to be proxied.  Unfortunately, one of the endpoints is `/` on the server but only for requests w/ a specific `Content-Type` header (I can't change the path this service is listening on, so adding some kind of path-prefix is not an option here).

I've tried using the `bypass` option in my WDS config to do something like this:

```
proxy: {
        "/": {
          target: "http://ows.local:6273",
          logLevel: "debug",
          secure: false,
          bypass: (req) => {
            console.log(`req.path => `, req.path)
            if (req.headers.accept.indexOf('html') !== -1) {
              console.log('Skipping proxy for HTML request.')
              return 'src/index.html'
            }
            return null
          }
        }
      }
```

The problem arises w/ initial calls for HTML, that which WDS should be serving up w/ the compiled `.js` and `.css` bundles injected.  All I get is the base `src/index.html` w/o the injected assets (no injected `<script>` tags).  This makes sense because I know I'm telling the proxy here, "Don't proxy this request to the target, just serve up the contents of this file", but that's not what I want. I need the compiled `index.html` that WDS serves as default, w/ the injected assets.

So here's my question w/ some specificity:

How can I essentially tell the proxy, "For requests that have `Content-type: application/json(or whatever)`, go ahead and proxy them through to the `target`, but for calls for `HTML`, don't proxy then, just serve up the WDS-compiled `index.html`"?

Comment: You should be able to do this on the frontend without any hazzle. I'd check the back-end proxy and filter out requests there instead to see if the problem is with the proxy or wds, if that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, all it took to solve this was to adjust the return value of the `bypass()` function.

```js
proxy: {
        "/": {
          target: proxyTargetUtl,
          secure: false,
          logLevel: "debug",
          bypass: (req) => (req.headers.accept.includes("html") ? "/" : null)
        }
```